# Unable to import PhoneLookup?

Tags: android

I am using the following code to get the name of the person from the contacts using his number but I am unable to import `PhoneLookup`?

```
 String contact=address;
 Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(address));  
 Cursor cs= context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},PhoneLookup.NUMBER+"='"+address+"'",null,null);

 if(cs.getCount()>0)
 {
     cs.moveToFirst();
     contact=cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you show us the exact import statement you are using. Based on [`ContactsContract.PhoneLookup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html) documentation, your import should be:

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
```

Note also that `PhoneLookup` is available starting with API level 5 (Android OS 2.0), so if your target is lower than that, you won't be able to find that import.

For 1.6 you can use `Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URL`. Details here - [How to look-up a contact's name from their phone number on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174048/how-to-look-up-a-contacts-name-from-their-phone-number-on-android)

Comment: thks i was using 1.6,do u have any alternate for it?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the deprecated [Contacts.Phones](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.Phones.html) if `PhoneLookup` is unavailable.