# Display contact names by part of phone number

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number

I have a function that takes a number and seeks for it into the phone contacts, but after that it returns the contact name.

```
public String[] getContactDisplayNameByNumber(String number) {
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
        String name = "?";
        String[] nameStr = {};

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor contactLookup = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] {BaseColumns._ID,ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);

        try {
            while (contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount() != 0 && !contactLookup.isLast()) {
                contactLookup.moveToNext();
                nameStr = insertElement(nameStr,contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                //String contactId = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
            }
        } finally {
            if (contactLookup != null) {
                contactLookup.close();
            }
        }

        return nameStr;
    }
```

What do I got to modify to make it search for a part of a number?
ex if the number is:0729587347, I want to search for 0729. 
If there are many contact starting with that number, I want them all(It is something like MYSQL %variable% search ...)! 
What's to do ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ContentResolver.query(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) can take a WHERE clause parameter.

Specifically, use something like:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
      new String[] {Data._ID, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL},
      Phone.NUMBER + " like ?",
      new String[] {"%"+String.valueOf(userInput) +"%"}, null);
```

For more examples, see the [ContactsContract.Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) javadoc.

Also, this is similar to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174048/how-to-look-up-a-contacts-name-from-their-phone-number-on-android).