# Get CONTACT_ID for a given number

Tags: android

I am trying to create a function that will take a `String` as an argument and it will return the `Contact_ID` for the contact that has a phone number like the `String` provided.

I have already found the following code

```
private String getContactName (String number) 
{
    String contactName = "";
    ContentResolver context = getContentResolver();

    /// number is the phone number
    Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
    PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, 
    Uri.encode(number));

    String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };

    Cursor cur = context.query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
    try 
    {
       if (cur.moveToFirst()) 
       {
          contactName = cur.getString(2);
          return contactName;
       }
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (cur != null)
            cur.close();
    }
    return contactName;
}
```

It returns all contactsName for a given number. 
How i can get the contact id from here?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
Could you provide me some example code?

Comment: You can fine some code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174048/how-to-look-up-a-contacts-name-from-their-phone-number-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to replace `cur.getString(2)` with `cur.getString(0)`. You already have the `_ID` as part of your projection (which BTW could be reduced to just the `_ID`).

Comment: I should mention that the _ID is just the row id is not the CONTACT_ID