# Comparing value stored in variable

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on an SMS application. I have designed the database so that my application does not get broken when the SMS content provider is removed. I have implemented some triggers to do clean-up work. I created the sms class using this statement:

```
`CREATE TABLE sms(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date_sent INTEGER DEFAULT 0, address TEXT, body TEXT, thread_id INTEGER);`
```

When the user would receive an SMS, the address of the SMS would contain his number plus country code. For me, it can be +91 9807 xxx xxx.

Suppose my table stores this address as 9807 xxx xxx. In case of triggers, a newly inserted row can be accessed with `new` keyword. So, to access the address, I would write `new.address`.

The Trigger is programmed in a way that depends on address and trigger only avails `address` information as new.address only.

My question is: how can I compare 9807 xxx xxx stored in the database against +91 9807 xxx xxx ?

Please note that I do not have direct access to either 9806 xxx xxx or +91 9807 xxx xxx. I can only reference them using address and new.address respectively.

Comment: Do you need SQL or Java expression?

Comment: I need SQL expression.

Comment: You should not save them with and without country code mixed because it is nearly impossible to compare them then. Country codes have 1 to 3 or 4 numbers and that makes it extremely hard. Android's SQLite has a hidden `PHONE_NUMBERS_EQUAL` function that you could use if you store them in a unified way.

Comment: @zapl: can you provide an illustration for `PHONE_NUMBERS_EQUAL' ?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2175483/995891) are some details about that function. It does not work on `+91 9807` vs `9807` but it works on `+91 9807` vs `+91-98-07`. It's used like any SQLite function: `DELETE FROM table WHERE PHONE_NUMBER_EQUAL(new.address, address)`

Comment: @zapl: Well, I am receiving error for PHONE_NUMBER_EQUAL and PHONE_NUMBERS_EQUAL.
It says no_such_function.